# A question about the condition of Frobenius theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I puzzled about the condition of Frobenius theorem:

Condition FR1:

Let $X$ be a manifold, $E$ is a subbundle of $TX$,vector fields $ ξ,η $ lie in $E$(i.e. $ ξ(x),η(x)\in E_x $),then bracket $[ξ,η]$ also lie in $E$.

I am puzzled whether the condition is satisfied by any subbundle $E$ of $TX$ because of the reason stated blow .

If $E$ is a subbundle of $TX$, $U$ is sufficintly small neighborhood of $x_0 \in X$,then there exist trivizlizations

$$ 
\tau_1 : TX_U\rightarrow U\times F_1\times F_2 $$
$$
\tau_2 : E_U\rightarrow U\times F_1$$

making the following diagram commutative:

$$
$$\begin{array}
AE_U & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & TX_U \\
\downarrow{\tau_2} & & \downarrow{\tau_1} \\
U\times F_1 & \stackrel{}{\longrightarrow} & U\times F_1\times F_2  
\end{array}

The bottom map is the natural one:Identity on $U$ and the injecction of $F_1$ on $F_1 \times 0  $.

If vector fields $ ξ,η $ lie in $E$,then local expression shows:

$$ξ :U\rightarrow F_1 \times 0  $$
$$η :U\rightarrow F_1 \times 0  $$

Hence 
$$[ξ,η]=η'ξ-ξ'η:U\rightarrow F_1 \times 0  $$
i.e. $[ξ,η]$ lie in $E$.

I am puzzled about it and I hope you can give an example or check out the mistakes I had made.

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Try $X=\mathbb R^3$, with the subbundle  $E\subset TX$ given as the kernel of $\alpha=dz-ydx$ (i.e. $v$ is a section of $E$ iff $\alpha(v)=0$) and the sections of $E$ $\partial/\partial y$ and $\partial/\partial x + y\partial/\partial z$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why it happens.

Bracket $[ξ,η]$ is not invariant under VB-isomorphism.

Example by user8268 :

$X=R^3$ , $ ξ(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,0,1,0),η(x,y,z)=(x,y,z,1,0,y)$,then$[ξ,η]=(0,0,1)$.

Under VB-isomorphsim:

$$f:TR^3 \rightarrow R^3 \times R^3$$

$$f(x,y,z,m,n,l)=(x,y,z,m,n,l-ym)$$

Then $f[ξ]=(x,y,z,0,1,0),f[η)=(x,y,z,1,0,0),[fξ,fη]=0 \neq f[ξ,η]=(x,y,z,0,0,1)$.